# Error al listar cliente en WCF

Tags: webservice, wcf

Estoy intentando listar un cliente con WCF y me aparece este error y he mirado que antes muchas personas lo han hecho así, talvés sea de configuaración.

Mensaje de error:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Y este es el código:

```
public List<Datos.cliente> listarClientesGeneral()
{
    using (TallerRefuerzoEntities conexto = new TallerRefuerzoEntities())
    {
        return conexto.cliente.ToList();
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfHotel
{    
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Datos.cliente> listarClientesGeneral();
    }
}
```

En el web.config tengo esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="TallerRefuerzoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Datos.Model1.csdl|res://*/Datos.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Datos.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DORADO-PC;initial catalog=TallerRefuerzo;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Este es mi error al invocar en el cliente de prueba wcf y en la parte de abajo colocaré el error al subirlo  al iis, tal vez sea de utilidad:

No se pudo invocar el servicio. Causas posibles: el servicio está sin conexión o inaccesible. la configuración del cliente no coincide con el proxy; el proxy existente no es válido. Consulte el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información. Para intentar la recuperación, inicie un nuevo proxy, restablezca la configuración predeterminada o actualice el servicio.

Error al recibir la respuesta HTTP a http://localhost:49612/Service1.svc. Puede deberse a que el enlace del extremo de servicio no usa el protocolo HTTP. También puede deberse a que el servidor anula un contexto de solicitud HTTP (posiblemente por el cierre del servicio). Consulte los registros del servidor para obtener más información.

Server stack trace: 
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   en IService1.Listar()
   en Service1Client.Listar()

Inner Exception:
Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de recepción.
   en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Inner Exception:
No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.
   en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   en System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   en System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

Inner Exception:
Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
   en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu codigo se ve bien, el error es de conexión, puedes poner la cadena de conexión? y hacer ping al server que te quieres conectar, validar por fuera de c# si en realidad tienes acceso.

Comment: Te voy a pasar todo e lweb.config, y si tiene porque yo he creado clientes y eliminado desde esa mismo servicio.


<connectionStrings>
     <add name="TallerRefuerzoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Datos.Model1.csdl|res://*/Datos.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Datos.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DORADO-PC;initial catalog=TallerRefuerzo;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Aquí te paso todo el config

http://admpruebas.tk/cnf.txt

Comment: Hola Alexis, la información relevante, como la del web.config tiene que ir en la pregunta, en la parte de abajo de tu pregunta hay un link para poder editarla. Como tu pregunta me pareció bastante buena lo colocaré por ti en esta ocasión, pero para futuros casos recuerda adjuntarlo directamente a la pregunta. Otra punto importante es que no pongas imágenes, incluso si son errores ponlos como texto, esto nos ayuda mucho a rastrear los diferentes errores y no andar transcribiendo todo :D

Comment: Perfecto, soy nuevo acá, valoro mucho las recomendaciones.

Comment: Alexis como estás; eso es justo mi problema también; como lo resolviste?. Gracias

Comment: En mi caso me tope con este error y es porque mi endpoint modificó la versión del TLS el Framework 45 solo puede utilizarse para TLS 1.1, actualice a Framework 4.6.2 y todo funcionó correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

El error de debe al `binding`, deseas iniciar con `http` pero tienes configurado `https`:

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
```

Cambia el `protocolMapping` o agrégalo para que también tengas `http` de la siguiente forma:

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
```

Si te das cuenta, tu *localhost* desea acceder por medio de http, el cual de momento no está configurado.

Comment: Gracias caballero, agregue lo que me dices y sigue apareciendo el error, he avanzado en el servicio,  puedo agregar, eliminar editar y consultar datos, pero que no sean más de uno, solo traer uno por uno, colocando el id puedo traer el nombre o apellido y así con todo.
Volvere a colocar lo que me aparece en el error en la pregunta pero en texto.

Answer (score 0):

En base a tu webConfig, es muy probable viendo esta línea:

```
<add name="TallerRefuerzoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Datos.Model1.csdl|res://*/Datos.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Datos.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DORADO-PC;initial catalog=TallerRefuerzo;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

que el usuario con el cual se ejecuta el programa no tenga acceso al BD

```
data source=DORADO-PC;initial catalog=TallerRefuerzo;integratedsecurity=True;
```

Hay 2 cosas que puedes hacer (son opcionales y excluyentes, osea que solo debes intentar una opción, ambas al mismo tiempo no tienen caso):

**A).** Utilizar Impersonate (solo hay que agregar esto al webconfig):

NOTA: Asegurate de poner un usuario y contraseña que si tengan acceso a la BD

```
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Windows"/>
      <identity impersonate="true" userName="usuario" password="contraseña"/>
    </system.web>
```

**B).** Crear un usuario de BD para el sistema, así conectarte mediante user y password (Tendrías que actualizar la cadena de conexión del web.Config):

```
    data source=(local);initial catalog=BisVales;user id=sa;password=123456789;
```

Comment: Hola Cristina :) esta vez tu respuesta no me hace sentido. Por el mensaje de error "*...el enlace del extremo de servicio no usa el protoco HTTP.*" indica que es un error en la comunicación al querer instanciar el servicio en el *localhost*, tengo la gran sospecha que hasta este momento no existe el acceso a datos para poder atacar por ese lado, si fuera eso se enviaría un mensaje de error de SQL, Oracle, MySql etc.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero puedes intentar lo que te digo también, entonces se me ocurre que puede ser firewall, o permisos en si propios del IIS.... si es por permisos te puedo ayudar el impersonate....

Comment: Por otra parte enlace de que servicio? no estas mencionando ningun servicio en tu código? a casos utilizas algún web services?

Comment: Sí, tienes razón, agotar todas las opciones disponibles para poder dar con el error. De tu segundo comentario, discúlpame, no logro comprender realmente tu pregunta, ¿será posible que me des más detalle?

Comment: Me refiero a que si porque marcaria error de http.... tal ves tiene que ver con la otra respuesta que te dieron, tiene mas sentido, me preguntaba en que momento te lanza ese error, si no es al intentar conectarse... entonces es en cuanto corres la aplicación?  alli si deberia ser alguna restriccion del iis... o configuracion de web.config, o hasta de firewall

Comment: Bueno, yo di la otra respuesta jeje, yo no soy el que pregunta. Ese mensaje de error se lanza cuando se inicia el depurador y básicamente se refiere a que no puede encontrar la ruta por medio del protocolo HTTP, y justo como lo decía en mi respuesta, es debido a que no lo tiene configurado. Respecto al firewall lo dudo ya que corre en *localhost*, lo que sí es posible es algún ajuste en el IIS local. Ese error también se puede dar al momento de consumir un WCF y que no encuentre la ruta, este no es el caso ya que en el código y en el error se muestra el mismo Service1.svc :)

Comment: Jajajaja, perdon no medi cuenta  XD pero bueno, el OP no ha dicho nada.. entonces... xD aver si lo puede resolver..... esperemos que pronto

Comment: xD no te preocupes, esperemos que nos responda pronto :D

Comment: Gracias amig@s, agregue lo que me dice el caballero @Flxtr y sigue apareciendo el error, he avanzado en el servicio, puedo agregar, eliminar editar y consultar datos, pero al consultar, que no sean más de uno, solo traer uno por uno, colocando el id puedo traer el nombre o apellido y así con todo. Volvere a colocar lo que me aparece en el error en la pregunta pero en texto.